# Built a GCC cross compiler toolchain successfully. How do I setup the enviornment variables properly?

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, environment-variables, cross-compiling, osdev

I do not know if this is the right place on how to setup the enviornment variables for a cross compiling toolchain. The toolchain's purpose is to develop OSes. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The problem is how do I setup the enviorment variables for the toolchain. The path of the cross compiler toolchain is

```
/home/Home/local
```

I want to be able to use GCC cross compiler toolchain but still be able to use the GCC toolchain that came with Ubuntu. If I am not clear please feel free to ask me some questions, or if you need more information about what I am want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you state a `--target=...` in your configure (which you are bound to do if you're setting up a cross-compiler), all resulting binaries will be prefixed with that target string; i.e., for `--target=i586-elf`, you will end up with `i586-elf-gcc`, `i586-elf-as` etc.. Those will not collide with your system compiler, so you can add `/home/Home/local/bin` to your PATH without problems. `gcc` will still be your system compiler, `i586-elf-gcc` your cross-compiler.

Ref. [OSDev.org](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC%20Cross-Compiler).